# Why is iOS sending HTTPS requests even with background refresh disabled?

Tags: ios

I've installed NextDNS on my iPhone and started noticing random connection requests to `*.aliexpress.com`, `live.musical.ly`, `amazon.sa`, and others.

What made me wonder is that

1. I don't have "background app refresh" enabled,
2. No app from TikTok, AliExpress, or Amazon is installed and
3. I had the phone locked ("standby") during the whole time.

Does anyone know what might be happening here?